# OpenSSL not working on window using PHP exec function

Tags: php, windows, encryption, exec, php-openssl

I'm using OpenSSL to encrypt the variable value and using PHP exec function but for some reason it is not working via PHP code.

```php
$secret = '339e0asdadf5cdf77sdfsdfe24e52130a55dsdfdfsd1';
$buf = array();
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$cmd = 'echo "'.$timestamp.'" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -k '.$secret;
exec($cmd, $buf);
$timestamp = implode("\n", $buf);

echo 'TimeStampValue1: '.$timestamp.'<br><br>';
echo exec('echo Hello World!');
echo urlencode($timestamp).'<br>';
```

When we're executing the command:

```
echo "2017-12-14 13:05:51" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -k 339e0asdadf5cdf77sdfsdfe24e52130a55dsdfdfsd1
```

On CMD it does shows the encrypted value. See attached screenshot. But, while executing same command on PHP script using exec function it's not working.

We've confirmed that:

- exec function is enabled in PHP configuration file.
- OpenSSL is enabled in PHP configuration file.
- OpenSSL path is also set on environment variables.
- PHP error log isn't showing any error in the code. Our error log maintains at c:/windows/temp

Not sure why this is not working seems like still things aren't configured properly in PHP.INI file using IIS as webserver.

Comment: You can do this without needing to call out to the executable: openssl_encrypt()

Comment: Yes, I also tried to use openssl_encrypt() but the third service provider is unable to decrypt the value on their end since they recommend to use openssl via exec function.

I used method "aes-256-cbc" but for exec in the above code method is "enc -aes-256-cbc -a -k" but for openssl_encrypt function "enc -aes-256-cbc -a -k" isn't working for openssl_encrypt function. Any suggestions so it encrypt the values same?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: *... [the] exec function it's not working"* is not a good problem statement. You should explain how it is not working, provide an error code, and provide {actual|expected} output. Also, I believe `echo` alone adds a new line, and they are different on Windows (CRLF), Linux (LF) and Unix (CR). Maybe the first step is to avoid the newlines.